# Re-creating Forest App's UI (Forest element) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, user-experience

I want to clone the [Forest: Focus for Productivity](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cc.forestapp&hl=en&gl=US) in Flutter. Specifically, I'm interested in recreating the forest part of the UI. I'm uncertain about the feasibility of achieving this solely within Flutter, or if I need to explore other options such as using plugins like Flame Game Engine or other 3D development platforms.

Could someone provide guidance on how to approach creating this effect in Flutter? Any relevant resources, code snippets, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you! :)

I tried to create it in `GridView` with a background but it didn't worked out well.